# What does the phrase "pull off sick wheelies and flips" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a made-up sentence from a racing game:

> In order to earn speed boosts, you should catch air and **pull off sick**
>   **wheelies and flips**.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "pull off sick wheelies and flips."

I know the meaning of the word [wheelie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wheelie), but cannot figure out the sense of the word **sick**. Also, I am not sure if the word **flip** conveys an act in air or on land.

Comment: Did "catch air" make sense though? ;) "Do interesting tricks."

Comment: Are you by any chance playing Uniracers (Unirally) for the Super Nintendo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> > pull off sick wheelies and flips.

To **pull off *something*** is a *phrasal verb*.  ("Pull off" is used together.) Here it means:

> to succeed in doing something difficult or unexpected.
>
> --- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-off-something)

The word **sick** is **slang** used by young people:

> (slang) very good, excellent:
>
> *snowboarders doing sick tricks*
>
> --- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sick#cald4-1-1-4)

As user @JamesK notes, it may be considered **dated**.  (Teenage slang moves pretty fast.)

A **wheelie** or wheelstand is a trick where the front wheel of a bicycle or a motorcycle comes off the ground:

> [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/Motor_cycle_stunt2_amk.jpg/220px-Motor_cycle_stunt2_amk.jpg]
>
> --- Photo: AngMoKio, [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelie)

And finally, a **flip** is another kind of trick, where either the person, or their equipment, flips over.

This can be on a motorcycle, a bike, or a skateboard, for example:

> [image: Photo showing skateboard flip]
>
> -- *Photo by Kirk Morales*, [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Kirk_Morales_2015_%28Unsplash%29.jpg/320px-Kirk_Morales_2015_%28Unsplash%29.jpg)

For more reading on skateboarding flips, try the articles [*Kickflip*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickflip) and [*Flip tricks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_tricks) on Wikipedia.  For bicycle (BMX) tricks, try [*Freestyle BMX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freestyle_BMX)  on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, _groovy_ and _rad_ have supplanted _sick_.

Comment: Or the reverse.

Comment: "very good but patently unsafe at an insufficient level of practice" :)

Comment: I don't think you'll find many under the age of 30 who use the slang "sick" anymore.

Comment: @AbraCadaver lmao! Actually tho, I'm thinking *lit*, *hype*, and *fire* are then Gen Z equivalents.

Comment: @wjandrea *hype* is for people and situations, mostly used ironically; *fire* is exclusively for music

Answer (score 10):

It is casual teen slang.

"Sick" means "very good" [(wikitionary sense 6)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sick#Adjective)

"Flip" is some kind of trick in which you rotate in the air.

Using "sick" in this way is, perhaps, already a little dated.

Comment: You mean "sick" isn't sick any more?

Comment: @DavidRicherby They got sick and tired of it.

Comment: Slang changes at a sickening pace.